# Join two tables ,in which one table have two foreign keys that reference to a single column in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[image: This is my contest table]

[image: This is my official_teams table]

team_1_id & team_2_id fields of "contest" table refers to id field of "officail_teams" table.

I want to join these two tables in a way that the final table should be like:-

```
id  ::::  team_1_name  ::::   team_2_name   :::::  status 
1   :::::::::: MI:::::::::::::::::::::::              CSK    ::::::::::::       upcoming
2   :::::::::: RCB:::::::::::::::::::::::              SRH   ::::::::::::       upcoming
```

Comment: To do this you need to join to the official_teams table twice with the different keys from contest, so your SQL would look something like :-

select team1.full_name, team2.full_name  etc ......
FROM contest
INNER JOIN official_teams team1 ON contest.team_1_id
INNER JOIN official_teams team2 ON contest.team_2_id

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should do it

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t2.short_name AS team_1_name,
    t3.short_name AS team_2_name,
    t1.status
FROM contest t1
INNER JOIN officail_teams t2 ON t1.team_1_id = t2.id
INNER JOIN officail_teams t3 ON t1.team_2_id = t3.id
```

All you should need to do is JOIN on the second table twice.

When you have the ID in the result however, I'm not sure which one you want so I've just used the one from the first table